# C: Segmentation fault while receiving address as input and assigning an array value to the address

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, byte

***Question: Write a program to copy the data from 4-byte variable to an array and vice-versa. (Input: integer and array start address)***

I have to receive an integer as input and store it in a 4 byte variable.
Also have to receive array address as input.

Then store the integer value in the array and print the result and also do the reverse of it.

I tried the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num,arr[]={0};
    int *ptr=NULL;
    scanf("%d%p",&num,&ptr);
    
    arr[0]=num;
    *ptr=num;
    
    printf("%p",ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

But there was a Segmentation fault (core dumped) error. What is wrong with the code?

Comment: You can't pick an address to write to - it must be a valid address that the program is allowed to write to.

Comment: In addition to the previous comment: it is very unclear what you're trying to achieve. Also this might be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: On modern protected operating systems, a process (running program) can't write to addresses it doesn't own. You can't just give an arbitrary address as input and hope that it somehow happens to be valid.

Comment: I have updated the question with the actual question that I was asked.

Comment: I think that by "array start address" what is really meant is "array start *index*". If you have received this assignment from a teacher, please as the teacher for clarifications.

Comment: Your array only has one element, there are no other array (addresses) you can choose.

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain a valid address using a malloc. In this case I allocated an int size for your example, print the valid address and then you can use the scanf in order to put this one.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main()
{
    int num,arr[]={0};
    int *ptr=NULL;
    int *p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    printf("p: %p\n", p);
    scanf("%d%p",&num,&ptr);
    
    arr[0]=num;
    *ptr=num;
    
    printf("%d",*ptr);
    free(ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- You need to set a size for your array.
- You can't choose some address for you parameter.

Here is the code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        int num, arr[1] = { 0 };
        scanf("%d", &num);
        arr[0] = num;
        printf("%p", &arr[0]);
        return 0;
    }
```